# Jekyll, modify the way some html tags are rendered

Tags: ruby, plugins, markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

I would like to modify the way some html tags are rendered on jekyll. What I need is to add some css classes automatically (in this case the ".table" class to the table html tag).

I'm using the redcarpet markdown processor. I suppose I need to write a plugin that extends the renderer but I can't find any good example...

I came up with this but it's just a copy/paste job and it doesn't work...

```
require 'redcarpet'

class BootstrapTables < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def table(header, body)
    "\n<table class='table'><thead>\n#{ header }</thead><tbody>\n#{ body }</tbody></table>\n"
  end
end
```

Someone can help?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the Bootstrap framework and I need to override it's style, a solution that I don't like too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way and corrected the code, I need a properly configured custom renderer. Using `RedcarpetExt` as markdown variable in the *_config.yaml* will activate it.

```
# Create a custom renderer that extend Redcarpet to customize its behavior.
require 'jekyll'
require 'redcarpet'

class RedcarpetExtender < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  # Extend the table to be compatible with the Bootstrap css.
  def table(header, body)
    "\n<table class='table-bordered table-hover'><thead>\n#{ header }</thead><tbody>\n#{ body }</tbody></table>\n"
  end
end

class Jekyll::Converters::Markdown::RedcarpetExt
  def initialize(config)
    @site_config = config
  end

  def extensions
    Hash[ *@site_config['redcarpet']['extensions'].map {|e| [e.to_sym, true]}.flatten ]
  end

  def markdown
    @markdown ||= Redcarpet::Markdown.new(RedcarpetExtender, extensions)
  end

  def convert(content)
    return super unless @site_config['markdown'] == 'RedcarpetExt'
    markdown.render(content)
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, am I supposed to use "markdown: RedcarpetMod" ? in the config? or where? I'm using github pages and have placed this RB file in the _plugins folder

Comment: Yes it should work like that but I don't know if it works on github pages. I modified the RB file a little, you find it on my [public site source](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m911o1xtlhhjdh9/AAAk8qZ5x8nxhGBByDiyvZhEa/ciroprincipe.info) (please note that now I'm using kramdown, but the redcarpet code is commented in the **_config.yaml**).

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work with GitHub Pages; they run Jekyll in safe mode, which disables custom plugins.

Comment: @cyrusza What made you switch to kramdown?

Comment: SpacyRicochet, I switched because at the end I found kramdown having all the features I need and constantly improving.

Comment: @SpacyRicochet GitHub pages now, only support [**kramdown**](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-your-markdown-processor-to-kramdown/)

Comment: @balexandre Thanks for the heads up. I should consider it as well now (might be stepping over to Github pages too).

Answer (score 9):

I've tested that you can give a class to a markdown element with **kramdown**

```
{:.foo}
| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
```

Your table has the class **foo**

NB :  [this answer was given one month ago on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732363/1548376)

Comment: This is nice but I have to switch markdown processor. I voted up your answer but I will wait more time for a code solution before accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: @cyrusza Any luck in adding classes in redcarpet?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be to use [sass Bootstrap version](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

This version is in synch with twbs/bootstrap and sass/scss is natively supported by Jekyll.

Then once you have sass working (is takes five minutes) you just have to create a rule in your custom style.scss file :

```
table{
  @extend .table;
}
```

And then every table will use .table bootstrap rules.