# Extending redcarpet for Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, redcarpet

I've found this post [Jekyll, modify the way some html tags are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748389/jekyll-modify-the-way-some-html-tags-are-rendered)

Which does explain how to extend redcarpet itself.
But what else needs to be done in order to get such extension to work?
What name does the extension correspond to in the _config.yml ?
Do I need to include anything in my gem file?

If I simply change "markdown: redcarpet" to "markdown: RedcarpetMod" github pages will send a main telling me that there were syntax errors in the first markdown file it tries to process.

Comment: My guess is Jekyll won't support modified markdown parsers, but if you want to ask the Jekyll maintainers, you could always post your question in https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stumbling block here is GitHub pages — the answer given by @cyrusza in the question you've linked works fine (I am using it to modify redcarpet's rendering on one of my sites).  GitHub pages, however, runs in safe mode which means that it does not allow custom plugins at all and instead only supports a few specific plugins.

Check the [Plugins page in the Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) for the note about safe mode (in the first blue box), and the [GitHub Pages help page about plugins](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/) for the list of which plugins are allowed.